# flutter doctor shows nothing

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

I was working on macOS to build flutter project and then I have to move the project to **windows server 2012 r2** to do API requests so I install the flutter in windows I create an initial project it works fine and then I tried to run my project 
first I run **'flutter packages get'** an error has appeared about the **./packages** file as well as error in updating pub it was trying to updating after each 5 seconds so I pressed **control+c** 
now when I run any flutter command nothing appears to me no errors no results what to do ??

Comment: How did you copy your project from Mac to Windows? Did you use `git clone`?

Comment: what is git clone? I put my source code on the server and opened it in the VSC directly

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a Flutter project from one machine to another, without using Git (`git clone ....`), then you need to delete all directories and files listed in the `.gitignore` file in your project (if the project was created with an older Flutter version another `.gitignore` file might be in `ios/` and `android/` - also delete the files and directories listed there).

`.gitignore` lists all files and directories that are specific to your machine and are generated on demand anyway, so there is no need to persist them.

It would be better to use Git even if you don't use GitHub or similar cloud services. You can use it only with a shared repository on a network share or even a repository on your local drive.

Comment: good, but the problem now the flutter commands not working I cant user 'flutter run', 'flutter packages get' or anything  and a notification appears said that "flutter setup: building flutter tool " and it  loads  without stopping

Comment: Did you delete the files and directories as explained?

Comment: Actually if `flutter doctor` does not work then there is a different problem because you don't need a project at all for Flutter doctor. I'd suggest you follow these steps to fix your Flutter install  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: what about unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool? and an infinite loop of trying to pub upgrade ?? please help me .. I'm not in China nither in India

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in my answer?

Comment: it shows me git is not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file :(

Comment: What is "it"? .

Comment: "the instructions in my answer" is about deleting directories. If you are talking about https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted, then you need to install Git if you do not have it yet.

Comment: **git is not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file**

Comment: flutter_tools depends on test >=1.5.2 which requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed .... this still appear

Comment: You didn't mention that error earlier. Please add your Flutter version `flutter --version` and your `pubspec.yaml` to your question.

Comment: I solved it by changing the location of flutter directory .. so meh but It works.. sir I tried to make git clone to my flutter project but this error appears **fatal: repository '/Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/Cloned' does not exist**